# Devise does not load custom CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

So, we recently started our change from a custom made authentication module to devise, and I am having a really bad time trying to figure out how to load my css into my devise views. I can properly load partials, even the ones from /layouts/, but it keeps trying to reach the css from /assets/devise, hitting a 404. 
This is my app/views/registration/new.html.haml, for instance:

```
%h2 Sign up
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div
    = f.label :password
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password
  %div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    %br/
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
  %div= f.submit "Sign up"
= render "users/shared/links"
```

So, any help will be really appreciated. =)

In a quick update: I already ran rails g devise:views.
I think the issue is that it is not loading my CSS inside the assets pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate the devise views first. Try this: `rails generate devise:views`. Then you can also customize the devise views.

Comment: I did it. This haml is located inside /app/views/registration/new.html.haml.

Comment: If public/assets exist, delete the folder.